# Golang windows service not writting to logfile

Tags: go, logging, windows-services

I have a simple TCP-server written in Go and running as windows service. It installs/uninstalls just fine, it is working as service and doing it's job but it's not writing a single word in a log file. When I run it simply as an executable in a console - logging works fine. But when it starts as a service - log file is created, application process opens it (thus disallowing to delete it for example) but file remains empty. What I'm doing wrong?

Any word of advice is appreciated.

logging is confured like this

```
func (p *Program) run() {
    exec, _ := os.Executable()
    WORK_DIR = filepath.Join(filepath.Dir(exec), "ATT")
    _, err := checkDir(WORK_DIR)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Не удалось создать рабочий каталог")
    }

    f, err := os.OpenFile(filepath.Join(filepath.Dir(exec), "server.log"), os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Не удалось создать лог-файл: %v", err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    wrt := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f)
    log.SetOutput(wrt)

    server, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+PORT)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer server.Close()
    log.Println("Сервер запущен на порту:", PORT)
    for {
        connection, err := server.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Не удалось установить соединение с клиентом", err)
        }
        go HandleServer(connection)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause would be `wrt := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f)`.

Below is the implementation of multiWriter . If writing fails in order, no more writing is done.

```
func (t *multiWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    for _, w := range t.writers {
        n, err = w.Write(p)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        if n != len(p) {
            err = ErrShortWrite
            return
        }
    }
    return len(p), nil
}
```

In Windows Service, stdout doesn't work. If you look at the error of wrt.Write, it will be `write /dev/stdout: The handle is invalid`.